# how I can use count and groupby at the same time?

Tags: python, pyspark

I want to count and groupby based on count, how I can do that?

For example I want to `groupby` `col1` on rows whose `count` is less than 3.

```
Col1          col2
"sal"         "salis"
"sal"         "salmon"
"bar"         "baran"
"dar"         "darya"
"sal"         "sald"
"bar"         "bard"
```

result

```
groupby   collect
"bar"      ["baran","bard"]
"dar"      ["darya"]
```

I know the following code gives me count of each element:

```
df1_us2.groupBy('col1').count().orderBy('count',ascending=False)
```

and use the following for groupby. but how I can combine these two?

```
df1_us2.groupBy('col1').agg(collect_list('col2').alias('collect'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First `groupby` and aggregate `col2` using `collect_list` then filter the rows where `size` of list is less than `3`

```
(
    df1_us2
    .groupby('col1')
    .agg(F.collect_list('col2').alias('col2'))
    .where(F.size('col2') < 3)
)
```

---

```
+-----+-----------------+
| col1|             col2|
+-----+-----------------+
|"bar"|["baran", "bard"]|
|"dar"|        ["darya"]|
+-----+-----------------+
```